# How do i use a variable defined already in a different function in another function?

Tags: python, function, global

```
def winOrLose():
   rand = random.randint(0,1)
   if rand == 1:
      win = 1
      return win
   elif rand == 0:
      lose = 0
      return lose

def scores():
    score = 0
    if win = 1:
       score += 1
    elif lose:
       score -= 1
```

I get an error when using the win and lose in the second function.

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling both of those functions?

Comment: globals are to be avoided in 95%  of programs, especially python. And if you must use a global, you certainly don't change its value inside a function.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use this variables outside this function as it returns the values. Instead use the functions return values directly:

```
def winOrLose():
   rand = random.randint(0,1)
   if rand == 1:
      win = 1
      return win
   elif rand == 0:
      lose = 0
      return lose

def scores():
    score = 0
    if winOrLose() == 1:
       score += 1
    else:
       score -= 1
```

Or even more simple without need of using variables `win`, `lose` and `rand`:

```
def winOrLose():
    if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def scores():
    score = 0
    if winOrLose():
        score += 1
    else:
        score -= 1
```

But there is one more thing: what do you do with your variable `score` in your function `scores`? Right now it does nothing but setting the local variable `score` to either `1` or `-1` and forget it right at the end. Maybe you want something like this to calculate a new score from an existing value and return the new result:

```
def calc_score(score=0):
    if winOrLose():
        return score += 1
    else:
        return score -= 1
```

Comment: `winOrLose` would typically be written with an even simpler body: `return random.randint(0,1) == 1`.

Comment: @chepner: You're right, but I tried to keep the function body similar to the original intention as OP may try to add some more functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I need to remember to direct comments like that to the OP.